# Find the remainder when $(34! + {75}^{37})^{39}$ is divided by $37$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Since Fermat Theorem is $a^{36} \equiv 1 \mod {37}$, ${75}^{37}$ becomes ${75}^{36} \times 75$ and in $\!\!\mod {37}$ they both become $1$.  I have $(34! + 1)^{39}$.  I do the same again with $(34! + 1)^{36} (34! + 1)^3$ and the power of $36$ number also becomes $1$.  I just dont know how to solve $(34! + 1)^3 \mod {37}$ at this point.

Answer (score 1):

By Wilson $36!+1$ is divisible by 37.

Thus, we work with
$$\left(\frac{-1}{-1\cdot(-2)}+1\right)^{3}.$$
I got the answer: $14$.

Comment: I don't think I've learned this method, I think we have to use Euler Theorem, although I'm not sure.  Is there anyway else to solve it?

Comment: @Kevin Wang It gives the answer immediately: $8$.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you got -1/2 x 3 then?

Comment: $34!=\frac{36!}{35\cdot36}\equiv\frac{-1}{-2\cdot(-1)}.$ My mistake. I fixed.